# Enable to Run Scrapy Project

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm quite new to Scrapy, I set up my project using this line `"scrapy startproject tutorials"` In terminal, I'm using Visual Studio Code.

I checked that:

1. The name of my property to be exactly the one I'm calling.
2. My `scrapy.cfg` is on the same path as my Script.
3. I checked that SPIDER_MODULES and NEWSPIDER_MODULE are well written in [spiders > setting.py]

This is my code:

```
import scrapy

class QuoteSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    start_urls = [
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.css('title').extract()
        yield {'titleText' : title}
```

my settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'quotes'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['tutorials.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'tutorials.spiders'
```

And this is how I'm running it:

```
scrapy crawl quotes
```

I'm still unable to run the crawler. What could be wrong ? Thanks.

**Edit:**

The error message I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Mohamed\Desktop\python 1\test python\Solution Test - ALIOUA WALID\tutorials>scrapy crawl quotes
2020-02-26 09:48:35 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.8.0 started (bot: quotes)
2020-02-26 09:48:35 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.3.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.10.0, Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48eceb, Dec 19 2017, 06:54:40) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 69, in load
    return self._spiders[spider_name]
KeyError: 'quotes'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
        "__main__", mod_spec)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
        exec(code, run_globals)
      File "C:\Users\Mohamed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 146, in execute
        _run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 100, in _run_print_help
        func(*a, **kw)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 154, in _run_command
        cmd.run(args, opts)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run
        self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 183, in crawl
        crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 216, in create_crawler
        return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 220, in _create_crawler
        spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)
      File "c:\users\mohamed\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 71, in load
        raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))
    KeyError: 'Spider not found: quotes'
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message you're getting on your terminal? Check if you're in the correct directory, that would be my guess

Comment: Seems almost right. If this is your exact code, you need to access the Spider class via scrapy.Spider.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: @furas Yes, I updated my post.

Comment: did you generate Spider - `scrapy genpider --help` ? It should create spider in subfolder with correct file name.

Comment: in `class QuoteSpider` you use `Quote` without `s` and it can be the problem.

Comment: @furas is it scrapy genspider --help ? It says the usage should look like this : scrapy genspider [options] <name> <domain>

Comment: @furas Tried with 's', but still the class name and not the robot name, right ?

Comment: it is use to generate spider - you have to add its `name` and `url` - and it should put it in correct folder with correct filename and set other important elements.  If you run code from `tutorial` in documentation then spider should be in folder `tutorial/spiders`

Comment: @furas It's working now, But still can't figure out what was wrong

Comment: see where do you have file with code - it search spiders only in `tutorial/spiders`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a Windows user or a Python expert so I'm not going to try detailed debugging of your paths and such but with the code you have posted, even when you do get your paths fixed and spider generated, it's still not going to "crawl" a website because you don't have any mechanism for it to find and follow links to additional URLs to scrape.

When you write "crawl" I'm assuming you mean multiple pages, if you just want the one page, I'd expect you to use terms like "fetch" or "parse" (or fetch then parse).

As others noted, try `genspider` but also add the parameters for the crawl template...if memory serves it is something like `scrapy genspider -t crawl quotes quotes.toscrape.com`

That'll give you a spider template with built in callbacks for finding and crawling additional URLs.